# How to return different type for a getter property in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, getter, android-livedata

I am trying to return a different type from a getter of a cretin filed.

```
private val _isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet : LiveData<Boolean>
get() =_isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet.value
```

but kotlin's compiler telling me that "getter return type must be equal to the type of the property" so is there an option to return value of a different type, or i should just write new function to get it's type?

Comment: There's definitely no way that is going to work. The type you are returning from the getter is obviously `Boolean`, so why are you declaring the property as `LiveData<Boolean>`?

Answer (score 1):

The getter should return `_isDeviceConnectedToTheInternet`,without the `.value`.

```
private val _isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet : LiveData<Boolean>
    get() =_isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet
```

Option 2:

```
private val _isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet : Boolean?
    get() =_isDeviceConnectedToTheInernet.value
```

Comment: of course you can do that, but i wanted to return a Boolean not a live data object...

Comment: Then the field should be of the type you want to return, so Boolean in this case.I edited my answer and added a solution for your comment.

Comment: But i want it to be of live data type... My question is it possible?

Comment: In your first comment you write you do not want a live data object, now you say you do? I am confused. I have given both options in my answer.

Comment: I want to return a different type in the getter from the field, I want the field to be of live data type and return in the getter a boolean type, is it possible? or do i need to write a function which will be the getter of this property?

Comment: Then just change the type of property.